# Xposed - hook private constructor

Tags: java, android, constructor, private, xposed

I'm using the Xposed module to analyze an android app, and I'm trying to hook a constructor that's declared as private, but it's unable to find the class. Is it because the constructor is private or is there another issue? The constructor is: `private CalendarContractCompat() {}`. My hook code is:

```
findAndHookConstructor("com.android.calendar.CalendarContractCompat", lpparam.classLoader, new XC_MethodHook() {
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to xposed bridge source (https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedHelpers.java), findAndHookConstructor calls getDeclaredConstructor and set its result to be accessible. That means the function should work on any constructor, public or not.

Can you hook a public method of the same class?

Comment: Are you able to hook private constructors? Xposed is throwing me a ClassNotFound error, although I'm hooking it just as I would for a public constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately, the class I'm analyzing only contains private constructors, for the main class and two nested classes, in terms of methods. The parent class is declared as final - would that make a difference? The two nested classes are declared as static final.